# Permanent email/chat indicator till click

Tags: 14.04, indicator

I use gm-notify and Empathy in Ubuntu 14.04. When these applications generate a notification, the email indicator, which is an envelope icon, turns to blue for a short time and then it returns its normal state, which is black in color. I want the icon to remain blue until I click the notification of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Recent Notifications](https://launchpad.net/~jconti/+archive/ubuntu/recent-notifications) indicator is a solution that I have just found.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jconti/recent-notifications
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-notifications recent-notifications
```